# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle

Tags: java, android, xml, inflate

I get the following error, or a similar error, every time my application tries to display a dialog fragment or particular layout:

```
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML   file line #51: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:385)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1484)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    ... 28 more
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=43; index=82
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:96)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:848)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:588)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    at com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle.<init>(DialogTitle.java:38)
11-22 10:20:48.993: E/AndroidRuntime(15514):    ... 31 more
```

The layout I am trying to display is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlelay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:padding="@dimen/small" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/problem_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_pad"
            android:background="#F00"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Login form -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warning_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titlelay"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warning_text"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_value"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_value" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/herds_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twenty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/livestock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twenty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addHoldings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twenty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twenty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This started occurring after I did some work defining style, color and dimension resources. I copied some layouts and resource files to another application, edited them there to get a new look, and copied them back into the main project. I have since (as far as I am aware) removed all those changes, but the problem still happens.

Another bizarre behavior is that an EditText in one functioning activity, that should be empty, is now filled with res/color/search_url_text_holo.xml.

I thought it might be that R.java had been corrupted. I've since deleted R, cleaned my project and rebuilt the project but this has not fixed the problem.

I'm really stumped. Any help at all would be great. Just ask if you need any more detail.

Thanks a lot.

Edit 1:
Here is the java code corresponding to the opening on the dialog:

```
private void arable() {
        dialogs.Arable arable = new dialogs.Arable();
        arable.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
}

package dialogs;

import rich.farming.fertiliserrecommendations.R;
import admin.reference.Crop;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import appmethods.Starters;

public class Arable extends DialogFragment {

    private static Activity act;
    private boolean cancelled;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        act = getActivity();
        int Items = R.array.Menu_arable;
        cancelled = false;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select").setItems(Items,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.out.println("(Dialogs.Arable.onClick which = "
                                + which);
                        switch (which) {

                        default:
                            cancelled = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        dismiss();
                        if (!cancelled)
                            act.finish();
                    }

                });

        return builder.create();
    }
```

This is just one example. There are multiple dialogs that are opened in this way. They were working great until recently. I can also post the menu resources if you like, but they have not changed.

Comment: are you opening any alertailouge just post java code here..

Comment: It's just a menu dialog. I've added the code that corresponds to it, but I'm not sure that it will be helpful.

Comment: just check your log cat showing arrayindexoutofbound exception..

Comment: I see that, but I don't understand what it means in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Bizarrely, it was because the resources element in my styles.xml contained a namespace reference:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Deleting that such that the element was instead:

```
<resources>
```

Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
You are puttin a too big String into one of your elements.
Hope this can help.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be happening. The dialog box I am opening doesn't actually reference any string resources and all strings in there are really short.